React chrome extension, active tab detect element on scroll is not working
Active tab's element on scroll is not working in react chrome extension.
Below is my code to detect active tab's document's element on scroll. But it's not working as expected.
I want 'Scrolled to end' to be consoled on scroll happens(when scroll ends... even if a small scroll happens).
Active tab's element on scroll is not working in react chrome extension.
Below is my code to detect active tab's document's element on scroll. But it's not working as expected.
App.tsx
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { useRecoilState } from 'recoil';
import messagesState from './states/messages';
function App() {
  const [htmlContent, setHtmlContent] = useRecoilState<any>(messagesState);


  useEffect(() => {
    const handleMessage = (event: any) => {
      if (event.data && event.data.type === 'scrollEnd') {
        console.log('Scrolled to end');
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener('message', handleMessage);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('message', handleMessage);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
     
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.type === 'scrollEnd') {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
      const activeTab = tabs[0];
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: activeTab.id },
        func: () => {
          window.postMessage({ type: 'scrollEnd' }, '*');
        },
      });
    });
  }
});

contentScript.js
let scrollTimeout;
const targetDiv = document.querySelector('.c-scrollbar__hider');

function sendScrollEndMessage() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'scrollEnd' });
}

targetDiv.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
  scrollTimeout = setTimeout(sendScrollEndMessage, 300);
});


manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "ASDF",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "ASDF",
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/slack-logo.png",
    "32": "images/slack-logo.png",
    "180": "images/slack-logo.png",
    "192": "images/slack-logo.png",
    "512": "images/slack-logo.png"
  },
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "contextMenus", "tabs", "scripting"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  }
}

I want 'Scrolled to end' to be consoled on scroll happens(when scroll ends... even if a small scroll happens).

window.postMessage doesn't work here because the popup is a different window, not related to the tab.

Use chrome messaging instead.

Remove content_scripts and use programmatic injection instead for something that you only use when the popup is shown, because this declaration needlessly runs the content script in every tab, wasting CPU and memory.

Remove background from manifest.json and the background script, you don't need it.

No need to unregister listeners in useEffect because the entire JS environment is destroyed when the popup is closed.

Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.


useEffect(() => {
  const handleMessage = (msg, port) => {
    console.log(msg);
    // right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu to see the console
  };
  chrome.windows.getCurrent(async wnd => {
    const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, windowId: wnd.id});
    chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(port => {
      if (port.sender.tab?.id === tab.id) {
        port.onMessage.addListener(handleMessage);
      }
    });
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: {tabId: tab.id},
      files: ['contentScript.js'],
    });
  });
}, []);

// contentScript.js
if (window.ACTIVE !== 1) {
  window.ACTIVE = 1;
  let scrollTimeout;
  const port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: 'scroll'});
  const el = document.querySelector('.c-scrollbar__hider');
  el.addEventListener('scroll', onscroll);
  port.onDisconnect.addListener(shutdown);
  function shutdown() {
    el.removeEventListener('scroll', onscroll);
    delete window.ACTIVE;
  }
  function sendScrollEndMessage() {
    if (!chrome.runtime.id) return shutdown(); // extension was reloaded
    port.postMessage({ type: 'scrollEnd' });
  }
  function onscroll() {
    clearTimeout(scrollTimeout);
    scrollTimeout = setTimeout(sendScrollEndMessage, 300);
  }
}


I did that, I followed your solution, But it's not working

You probably looked at the wrong console (the popup has its own devtools) or didn't copypaste the code correctly or didn't reload the extension after editing. You need to debug the code in devtools for the popup by setting breakpoints and then pressing Ctrl-R inside devtools to reload the popup. Also make sure you open the popup by clicking the extension icon and not as a localhost page from your IDE.

I did the same what you had suggested. Removed content scripts and background from manifest.json. and cleaned up background script, copied and pasted the same code snippet to contentScript.js, and in copied the same what was in the app.tsx to my app.tsx

Did you debug the code in devtools for the popup by setting breakpoints and then pressing Ctrl-R inside devtools to reload the popup?

Did you reload the extension in chrome://extensions page? Do you open the popup by clicking the extension's icon in the toolbar? Do you open the correct devtools by right-clicking inside the popup and selecting "inspect" in the menu?

I removed and loaded again... I did everything

So what exactly happens when you debug in devtools by setting breakpoints and reloading the popup? Debugging is a fundamental part of programming and really helps understand the way extensions work. Maybe you should start by using vanilla JS without React, and only when you see how it works, integrate it into React, because apparently there's a problem in your react config or you still look at the wrong devtools console.

I'm unable to debug since I'm not getting when I open inspect, I'm not getting app.ts or contentscript.js nor comments in content script.js because I'm building it using webpack and then I'm loading it in chrome as extension

It means your config is incorrect because there should be a script in devtools when inspecting the popup. I suggest that you install an official example extension with an action popup and see how it works, add the code shown in this answer, see how it works in devtools, then fix the config for react and integrate the code.

I tried and failed to find a proper boilerplate. If you find any boilerplate for react chrome extention which we could debug, run in dev mode then please drop the link here. Thank you

I don't use React, so I can only reiterate my suggestion to start with a vanilla JS example.

I found the issue. It is with html...
I'll fix it. When will we disconnect? from frontend?
port.onDisconnect?

port.onDisconnect is fired when the popup is closed or reloaded.
